# Angular 4 + Universal : Has no exported member 'StaticProvider'

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-universal

I got troubles with latest Angular 4 and universal, strange behaviour in bundling... 
I am using Webpack for the builds. All my configs is looks like valids. I am tried to use the demo app with empty div and "hello world" text inside, but error doesn't gone. Idk wtf is hapn...

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@nguniversal/express-
engine/src/main.d.ts:2:33
TS2305: Module '"webclient/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member "StaticProvider"'
```

Package.json and Tsconfig listings below:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.4.4",
    "@angular/core": "~4.4.4",
    "@angular/http": "~4.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/router": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/animations": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "~2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "~2.0.0-beta.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.4.4",
    "@angular/material": "~2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "~5.0.0-beta.1",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "~5.0.0-beta.1",
    "@types/webpack": "^3.0.12",
    "angulartics2": "~2.4.0",
    "core-js": "~2.5.1",
    "md2": "~0.0.28",
    "moment": "~2.18.1",
    "ng2-device-detector": "*",
    "ng2-filter-pipe": "*",
    "ng2-md-datatable": "~1.4.0",
    "ng2-ui-auth": "~7.0.2",
    "ngx-chips": "~1.5.3",
    "ngx-cookie": "*",
    "rxjs": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-helpers": "~1.1.2",
    "tslerp": "~1.0.5",
    "web-animations-js": "~2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.18"
 },
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~4.4.4",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~1.7.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.6.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.0.31",
    "angular2-template-loader": "~0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "~3.2.3",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "cpy-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "http-server": "~0.10.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "~0.6.0",
    "node-sass": "~4.5.3",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.10",
    "ts-node": "~3.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4"
  }
}
```

---

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": ["node_modules/@angular/*"]
    },
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "moment",
      "jasmine",
      "node",
      "source-map",
      "uglify-js",
      "webpack"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "node_modules/*",
    "**/*.e2e-spec.ts",
    "dist"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Paste your code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won this problem!
Just downgrade versions of these packages:

```
@nguniversal/express-engine
@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader
```

to the  ^1.0.0-beta.3